# Online knowledge management tool

Tags: knowledge-organization, knowledge-base

Looking for an online knowledge management tool. I need only very simple functionality:

- add articles (free text or w/simple markup);
- tag articles;
- full-text search over KB.

Is there a online option to do so?

**P.S.** It's for my personal use, so no need for access restrictions (it's all private for me, like Trello private boards).

Comment: "online option" suggests that it should be a hosted Web app, is that  correct? Do you need access restriction? Do you have a budget?

Comment: @unor Updated the topic. No budget, for personal use only.

Comment: With access restriction I mean if the content shold be publicly available or only behind a login. If I understand your edit correctly, you *do* want to restrict access, right? (though I don’t know Trello, so maybe there it’s public?) -- And what about my first question? (it should be a Web app hosted by someone else, is that right?)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) since it's perfect for small projects but highly versatile and expandable with plugins, above that it's open source and doesn't require a database.

You can either run it on a server or on your desktop – or both and sync it by using the [Synchronization Plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:sync).

DokuWiki is out there since 2004, actively maintained by its main-developer and has quite a large community and I think it's safe to say that it will be around for a very long time…